# Theoretically can REST API calls be made from any internet connected device?

Tags: rest

I am trying to understand REST API.Also,the question is can the REST API call be made through ANY internet connected devices?Including IOT devices?

Comment: if You ask ab. extremly low resources, few alternative protocol exist (non REST, not HTTP). Example: messaging via MQTT. But in generally, Yes, microcotrolers having network can use REST

Answer (score 1):

Does it have a HTTP client you can use? If yes, then you can probably call a REST api.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the REST API call be made through ANY internet connected devices?

REST is an *architectural style*. It is protocol independent but it's usually implemented over the HTTP protocol.

So, if your client supports HTTP, then *yes*, you can consume a REST API built on the top of the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the device as consisting of perhaps three main parts. The hardware that makes it what it is, e.g. a RasberryPi with a camera that's pointed at the sky, something to extract that essence and something to represent that essence on the internet.

The Pi has a wifi card and is connected to the internet but it can't call a REST API because all it has is a camera.

Someone comes along and writes a small program, perhaps in Python that downloads an image of the sky once a minute and analyses it for clouds and works out the percentage cloud cover.

Someone else comes along and writes a small program to read the percentage cloud cover using the previous program and send it to a server over HTTP in a REST format.

So yes, theoretically any internet connected device can use REST if 'what it represents' (in this case cloud cover) can be converted to something that can be 'represented' somewhere else. IOT devices may have all three parts baked into the hardware or they may have an onboard API and you develop and upload the REST part (think Arduino type devices).